The confusing output when calling `cout << function_name` and `cout << function_pointer`
I understand that std::string str(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t),std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()) is a declaration of plain function, why the output of the code snippet below
is

1
1

other than the address of a plain function, say

0x4591
0x4591

Here is the aforementioned code snippet:
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <streambuf>
#include <iostream>


std::string str(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t),
                 std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()){
            return {};
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    std::cout << &str << std::endl;
}


std::cout doesn't have an overload to print the address of a function but does have an overload to output bools.  Function addresses can implicitly convert to bool.

This is relevant: How to print function pointers with cout?.
